# Redirect in htaccess from one path to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to change our site structure a little bit and decided to have the product overview not in http://www.example.com/en/ but in http://www.example.com/en/products/

I did not manage it to redirect it from /en/ to /en/products/ (or /en to /en/products/).

The page is not online so far (Testmode) and I don't have to care about 301 Pages for Google at the Moment.

Can anybody help?

Comment: if the website isn't online then why are you concerned with redirecting like this? You can replace all /en/ links to /en/products/? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to write this rule yourself?

Comment: The page is in development and online in a password protected area. I've tried: Redirect /en/ /en/products/ [L] but can't get it to work.